# This basic programme I wrote for exponents only works with integers - what did I do wrong?

Tags: java, math, exponent

I am building some basic programs as a way to practice different programming techniques. I thought I had written a programme to calculate exponents but it doesn't work correctly.

It works fine if I input integers ie. squared (2,5) but (2,4.5) doesn't work.

```
public static double squared(double a, double b) {
    double a1 = a;
    double sq = 0;      
    while (b > 1) {
        sq = a*a1;
        a =sq;
        b--;
    }
    return sq;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(squared(2,2));
}
```

Comment: I see you are using a while loop, if the input to `b` is `4.5`, how many times will this loop "loop"?

Comment: Thank you kindly sir.

So obvious that I:  squared(facepalm, 10);

Comment: As I couldn't  see any problem I copied it and tried it: no problem at all. squared(2,4,5) gives 32.0 as it should. You didn't expect it to do a multiplication, that is only performed till half ways done and suddenly stops in the middle  or something, did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works as expect if `b` is an integer, because your code assumes `b` is an integer.

The same result will be computed whether `b` is 4 ou 4.5, because both 0 and 0.5 are smaller than 1 (thus ending the loop).

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm works for integer numbers, but in order to calculate the power with a floating point exponent, your approach wont work.

First, let's clear what a float exponent means by taking your example of `pow(2, 4.5)`:

[image: 2^{4.5} = 2^{\frac{9}{2}} =\sqrt[2]{2^{4}}]

So in order to calculate this, first we have to transform the floating point number to a fraction and then calculate the power and square root. This doable, but it's very tedious and they are far more better solution to do this.

If we have [image: A = x^{b}], where `b` can be a floating point number and `A` is the result, we can take the logarithm of both sides:

[image: \log(A) = b \log(x)]

Which is equivalent of:

[image: e^{\log(A)} = e^{b\log(x)}]

Which simplifies to:

[image: A = e^{b\log(x)}]

Now this can be done in Java very easily:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double a = 2;
    double b = 4.5;
    double A = Math.exp(b * Math.log(a));
    System.out.println(A);
}
```

If you don't want to use the built-in `exp` function, we can use the Newton-Raphson formula to calculate it:

[image: e^{x} = 1 + x/1! + x^{2}/2! + x^{3}/3!...]

where: `!` denotes the factorial of a number. 
Your initial algorithm can be used to compute the `pow` of an `x` with integer exponent.